# CLion Custom Function Template Generation?

Tags: c++, clion

Is there a way in CLion to create custom function templates for easily inserting a lot of repetitive junk from a parameter or more?  As an example the following would ideally take a parameter of `FUNCTION_NAME`:

```
/*
* FUNCTION_NAME
* 
*/
void FUNCTION_NAME() {
    try {

    } catch (CustomException e) {
        e.StackTrace.Add("at FUNCTION_NAME");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: CLion easily supports live templates, if that's what you're asking. As an aside, don't catch by value, but by (const) reference, and don't rethrow the exception with `throw e;` but with `throw;`. Creating the stack trace manually is quite questionable, you may want to use an exception class that saves the stack trace on throw instead.

Comment: It is questionable, I was just trying to think of some fluff quickly for the question.

Answer (score 1):

CLion supports [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/simple-parameterized-and-surround-live-templates.html)
The sequence of actions for your case is shown in [image: the picture]

Comment: This works for inserting new functions inline, though what about inserting things like a function header in a class header and the body inside of a cpp file?  I'd be fine with the `Generate definition for function 'foo'` method built into the IDE, except changing the code template for it doesn't seem to let me use `$FUNCTION_NAME` or `$ARGUMENTS`, only `$RETURN_TYPE`.